# Code Golf: Create a string of 100 of the same character

Tags: code-golf, string

The problem is to create a string of the same character repeated 100 times.

One potential solution in JavaScript is:

```
var i = 100,
    s = '';

while(i--) s += "Z";
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: This site is intended for puzzles only, not for practical problems. This creates three issues: 1. The task is too trivial to be interesting as a puzzle. 2. The really short answers aren't in JavaScript, so they won't help you. 3. In code golf, O(n) algorithms will have O(n!) implementations, undefined behavior will be invoked and pretty much anything else that should never, ever be present in code that is actually going to be *used* will be done, if it saves just a single byte.

Comment: I edited the question to be on topic but still allow for the existing answers.

Comment: Some answers took “create a string” literally and only generate the value leaving it lost in the RAM, while other answers stick with the default of outputting/returning the result. For trivial tasks like this, outputting/returning the result in some languages doubles the code length. I am not sure if this question is ready to be reopened.

Comment: 3-[byte](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) answer: `⁶×³`. This is surely too trivial.

Answer (score 9):

### golflua: <s>109</s> 15

```
w(S.t("a",100))
```

Which is more-or-less equivalent to [Heiko's Lua answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28125/11376)

Answer (score 6):

## Python2.7 - 7 bytes

```
'a'*100
```

String manipulation using `*` pretty simple.

Answer (score 6):

## Lua, 24 bytes

This variant is based on Geobits' [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28113/code-golf-create-a-string-of-100-of-the-same-character/28125?noredirect=1#comment60670_28125):

```lua
print(("").rep("a",100))
```

---

### Older version, 38 bytes

```lua
a=""for i=0,99 do a=a.."a"end print(a)
```

**Ungolfed:**

```lua
a = ""              -- start with empty string
for i = 0, 99, 1 do -- 100 times
  a = a .. "a"      -- append "a" to variable a
end
print(a)            -- print result
```

Comment: `print(string.rep("a",100))` ?

Comment: @Geobits: Very good, much shorter (26 bytes).

Comment: `print(("a"):rep(100))`, use the object implementation of `string.rep`, 21 Bytes ;)

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript, 4 characters:

```
100*
```

The input should be on the stack. This program assumes a single-character input.

[Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydhJwoKMTAwKg%3D%3D).

If the character needs to be hardcoded, it's **7 characters**:

```
'a'100*
```

If the character is a newline and it needs to be hardcoded, **5 characters** (thanks to Jan Dvorak):

```
100n*
```

Comment: Umm... are you expecting a single-character input? Because 100 times nothing is still nothing.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, I am. The OP gave an example where he appended a single character 100 times, so I assumed that the input will always be a single character.

Comment: In his case, the character was hard-coded in the statement. I that as that you are required to hard-code your own as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Ah, ok. I added an answer where the character is hardcoded, but I'll still keep the not-hardcoded part around if hardcoding the char is not necessary.

Comment: You can reduce the 7-character solution to 5 characters if said character can be a newline: `100n*`.

Comment: also, ``n`25*`` is an interesting solution ;-)

Comment: I think the 7-character solution is the only valid one

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript - 20 chars

At least, shorter than Bash ;)

```
Array(101).join("a")
```

An array of length `100` joined with letter `a`.

## Perl - 12 chars

First Perl golf !

```
print"a"x100
```

Thanks to ace for shortening one character.

Comment: `Array(100).join(a)`  - 18 characters. An array of length `100` joined with a letter from variable `a`! :D

Comment: Is this a Ninja edit or did I not notice your Perl answer before I posted mine? And P.S. you can remove the space between `print` and `"a"x100`

Comment: The Javascript solution should be `Array(101)`. `Array(100).join("a").length == 99`

Comment: @nderscore Thanks, fixing.

Comment: @ace I had just quickly applied my new Perl skills to my post, and noticed that we had posted the same answer at the same time. I was about to notify you, but the electricity went out. And thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 4):

## QBasic : 22

```
PRINT STRING$(100,"A")
```

Why not?

Answer (score 3):

## Bash+tr, 20 bytes

```
$ printf %100s|tr \  Z
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ$
```

---

## Pure Bash, 31 bytes

```
$ printf -vs %100s;echo ${s// /Z}
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
$
```

Pretty standard stuff.

---

## GNU dc, 14 bytes

```
2 800^255/90*P
```

Output:

```
$ dc -e '2 800^255/90*P'
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ$
```

Answer (score 3):

## J (7)

Very similar to the Python one

```
100$'a'
```

`100$'ab'` would output 50 times `ab`, for 100 characters total.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 7 bytes

```
"a"x100
```

Almost completely the same as the Python one.

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 27 characters (or <s>26</s> 25)

```
,>++++++++++[<..........>-]
```

This program requires input, because hardcoding a character is not possible in Brainfuck.

If it is allowed to always output 100 times the NUL character, there is a 25 char solution (thanks to Quincunx):

```
++++++++++[>..........<-]
```

Comment: Well actually it is possible... if you remove `,` you will be outputting 100 times of the NUL character.

Comment: @ace: Correct, but then you cannot specify the character.

Comment: The question never said the character has to be specified anyway...

Comment: @ace: The `Z` character is specified in the question, so a NUL character would probably be invalid.

Comment: This is how I interpret it: "...to create a string of **the same character** repeated 100 times in as short a statement as possible. **One potential solution** is:" If you interpret it as having to output the `Z` characters for 100 times then I think it is still possible in BF: you need to add 90 `+` in front.

Comment: @ace: Hmm... that could be indeed. I added it as an alternative solution. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if you could output the NUL character, you could simply do `++++++++++[>..........<-]`, saving 2 chars from your 27

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell

```
replicate 100 'a'
```

GHCi output:

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Code for GHC:

```
main = print $ replicate 100 'a'
```

Comment: No need for the space between `100` and `'a'`.